# read and change variables from another class?

Tags: objective-c

Hi i am wondering if anyone knows if it is possible to read a variable which is in AppDelegate from another class like ViewController.m

I am using the latest version of Xcode just so you know

EDIT:

This is the code i used to get two date variables from AppDelegate. But the variables never contain anything they just seem to be blank.

```
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [appDelegate->enterForgroundDate timeIntervalSinceDate:appDelegate->enterBackgroundDate];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to cast this to your specific AppDelegate class but yes:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Comment: Thank you what is the line of code to get a specific variable from the app delegate?

Comment: ((YourAppDelegateClass)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).yourPublicVariable;

Comment: Sorry but am i meant to put this inside the if statement or just in the viewdidload void of my .m file?